# Gauss Theorem used in the proof of Liouville's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am using the 2nd Edition of PDEs by L.C.Evans.

on Page 29 the following theorem is stated:

> #### Theorem 7 (Estimates on derivatives).
>
> Assume $u$ is harmonic in $U$. Then
>
> $$|\nabla u(x_0)|\leq \frac{C}{r^{n}}\|u\|_{L^1(B(x_0,r))}$$
> for each ball in $B(x_0,r) \subset U$

note: this is a special case of the original version, which is a more general kth order of gradient.

And the Proof:

> #### Proof
>
> - $u_{x_i}(x_0)$ is harmonic if $u$ is harmonic
> - apply the mean value formula for $u_{x_i}(x_0)$
>   $$\begin{split}
>   |u_{x_i}(x_0)| & = |\frac{2^n}{\alpha(n)r^n}\int_{B(x_0,r/2)}u_{x_i}dx| \\
>    & = |\frac{2^n}{\alpha(n)r^n}\int_{\partial B(x_0,r/2)}u\nu_idS|
>   \end{split}$$
>   ...

I stop because my question is here.

I know here Gauss Theorem is applied but I think Gauss Theorem is for divergence and not partial derivative on a single dimension.

Comment: Apply the divergence theorem to a vector field with only one non-zero component.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have sketched it into an answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [RRL](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/148510/rrl), I mananaged to understand the steps

let $v$ be a n-dimensional constant vector field with the $i$-th element being $1$ and others $0$. Then
$$u_{x_i} = \nabla u\cdot v$$
And for the vector field $uv$ we have the following (note that $u$ is $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R})$)

$$\nabla \cdot (uv) = \nabla u \cdot v + u\textbf{div}(v) = \nabla u\cdot v$$

so
$$u_{x_i} = \nabla \cdot (uv)$$
$\nabla \cdot (uv)$ fits the divergence theorem and and we can use it to achieve the 2nd "$=$"